# IE XdomainRequest CORS issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cors, xdomainrequest

I'm having an issue with IE (only IE8+, Chrome works just fine) where when I try to post information to another page on my website I get an error saying that "Origin `http://localhost:7230` not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header". I understand this has to do with CORS in some way but I'm no going outside of my domain.

The page that sends the request is: `http://localhost:7230/TestPage.aspx`

The page I am trying to post to `http://localhost:7230/ActionHandler.aspx`

The code to post to the page:

```
function RequestData()
   {
      //If we have no data don't request anything, just reset the timer
      if (dataStore.topReadings.length == 0 && dataStore.specifiedRanges.length == 0 && dataStore.entireRanges.length == 0 && dataStore.periodRanges.length == 0)
      {
         setInterval(RequestData, options.interval);
      }

      var params = "?Action=GET_DATA";
      var body = GetRequestXML();

      var xmlhttp;

      if (window.XDomainRequest) // code for IE8 and IE9
      {
         xmlhttp = new XDomainRequest();
         if (xmlhttp)
         {
            xmlhttp.onerror = function ()
            {
               alert("[Data Config]Failed to send request for configuration!\n" + xmlhttp.responseText);
            };
            xmlhttp.ontimeout = function ()
            {
               alert('xdr ontimeout');
            };
            xmlhttp.onprogress = function ()
            {
            };
            xmlhttp.onload = function ()
            {
               if (xmlhttp.responseText)
               {
                  HandleResponseData($($.parseXML(xmlhttp.responseText)));
               }
            };

         } else
         {
            alert('failed to create xdr');
         }
      }
      else
      {
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) // code for IE7, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         {
            try
            {
               xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            catch (e)
            {
               alert("[Data Request]Failed to create XMLHTTPRequest!\n" + e.message);
            }
         }
         else       // code for IE6, IE5
         {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }

         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function ()
         {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
            {
               //alert("Handled!");
               HandleResponseData($($.parseXML(xmlhttp.responseText)));
               that.trigger("dataReceived");
            }
         }
      }

      try
      {
         xmlhttp.timeout = options.timeout;
         xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:7230/ActionHandler.aspx" + params, true);
      }
      catch (e)
      {
         alert("[Data Request]Failed to open XMLHTTPRequest!\n" + e.message);
      }

      setTimeout(function () { xmlhttp.send(body); }, 0);
   }
```

This is an ASP.NET website running in visual studio. I've followed the steps [here](http://www.figers.com/Blog/2013/03/21/enable-access-control-allow-origin-in-iis6-iis7-for-webapi-calls/) and added the relevant lines to my web.config file. Any help on how to get my requests through to the ActionHandler page would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you watch your network traffic using Fiddler or F12's Network tab, is the POST getting sent, and is there an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on the response?

Comment: You shouldn't use XDomainRequest unless you're trying to go cross-domain; that object suffers from several bugs including failing completely in IE8 if the user is running in InPrivate mode. If you do need to eventually go cross-domain, your code here prefers XDomainRequest over CORS-XHR in IE10; it probably shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks for the info Eric. The response does have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. I got frustrated and tried the `$.ajax()` call and that works. I think my issue was my use of the XDR as you have suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you'll see this if you're posting from one domain to another or if you're posting from an `http` source to an `https` end point even on the same domain.

Have you tried setting this header?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"
```

Obviously using `*` is a bit too broad and you'll want to narrow but see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: That would make sense but as far as I know I'm not posting to different domains nor am I posting through different protocols.
I'm pretty sure I've set that. If you read the last lines of my questions I followed a guide that explained how to add that header and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: FWIW, IE fails immediately without the error message in question if you try to use XDR to go from http->https or vice-versa. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx